# Is there a way to render an image using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, image, svg, google-apps-script, png

I'd like to generate a graphic using data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet and then embed that graphic in a Google Document. There are lots of libraries to do this however they either require access to the DOM or node.js.

The graphic isn't supported by the chart API.

As I understand it neither of these are available in the Google apps script environment.

Is there a way to create custom graphics in google apps script?

Comment: DOM is available in the sidebar

Answer (score -1):

You could try setting up a function on Apps Script to [generate the graph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#build) and then [insert it into the document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendImage(BlobSource)) using the method appendImage() like:

```
docs.getBody().appendImage(chart);
```

To create a custom chart from Apps Script you could use the [Chart API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts)

Comment: That seems like the only option however the graphic I want to produce isn't supported by the chart API. I have updated the question.

Comment: Which graphic are you trying to create, because if this is not supported by the chart API, you should be able to put an image of the resulting graph in the docs with the `appendImage()` function.

Comment: A hex grid with variable data in each hex. So not a bar chart or similar. I need to be able to create a custom PNG server side. An SVG to PNG renderer would work however all of the examples I have seen use an actual browser to do the work which can't work in server side apps script.

Comment: If you are creating the graph using a third party API you should upload the file to drive and then insert it to the docs either manually or automated somehow, but doing the full process from Apps Script is not viable.